# wrap "inline-block" div around image

Tags: css

I need a "display:inline-block;" (not display:block;)  div around an image like this :

```
`<div style="display:inline-block;"><img src="#" /></div>`
```

The result is that div is bigger than the image. can I wrap it around the image giving it the same height and width? (without setting dimension).

Comment: have  you try `vertical-align: top;` with `display: inline-block;`

Comment: I made the solution above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `vertical-align: top;` to `<img>`

**CSS**

```
.wimg{
    display:inline-block;
}

img{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/0gjz1rtw/3/)**

Comment: Note that using `vertical-align: bottom` also works.

Answer (score 1):

The extra whitespace is due to how CSS positions elements around the baseline of the line box of the content.

If you apply `display: block` to the image, then you get the shrink-to-fit effect that you want.

The alternative approach of applying `vertical-align: {top|bottom}` to the image also works.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
div img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" />
</div>
```

Comment: Note that `display: block` is out of question

Comment: The OP wants the `div` not to be `display: block`.  I applied `display: block` to the image.